# Weird artifacts after rendering also when imported

Tags: modeling, rendering, import

Does anyone know know what would be causing these artifacts in the mesh, only visible during rendering and when imported into UE4?.[image]

Comment: Looks like the faces aren't planar + flat shading makes this apparent.

Comment: I'm not sure if i know what you mean they should be flat and it looks flat until a render is done. All i did was start with a plane extruded that into a cube, did some loop cuts, proportionally scaled the sides then dissolved the loop cuts, made a new loop cut at the top of cube lifted that loop cut to form the peak. everything should be planar and flat as you mentioned so idk?. it definitely sucks though. I'm going to re-do it here shortly and see what happens

Comment: Guessing what went from a single screenshot is difficult. I assume you've already ruled out the usual suspects *flipped normals* and *duplicate vertices*?

Comment: I know i took care of the normals not sure about the vertices though.